# how to combine multiple CSV files from multiple folders in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have several CSV files each represents data for a day with no header! more like month-1/day-1.csv ... day-30.csv - month-2/day-1.csv ... etc 
how can I combine all of these CSV files into one big CSV file that contains all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi quant and welcome to SO!

You can use following code to do this:

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = '/your_directory_containing the files'
os.chdir(path)

all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format('csv'))]

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Please note, that this code will combine all `.csv`-files in the specified directory.

I hope the code works for you :)

Comment: I beleieve OP wants multiple directory to be combined. Op you can find above answer at https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-combine-multiple-csv-files-with-8-lines-of-code-265183e0854/

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that your input is in a `in_data` folder and the output goes into a folder called `out_data` and both folders are in the directory of your notebook.

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

dfs = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in glob.glob("./in_data/month*/day*")])
dfs.to_csv("./out_data/df_combined.csv", index=False)
```